# Submit a form loaded thru Ajax with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that is loaded dinamically after the user select a series of options.

Once the form is displayed the user must click in a button in the form to confirm the selections and be redirected to a third party site.
Previous of the user being redirected I need to inform our system that the user has confirmed the options and generate an ID to pass the third party site so it can identify the transaction.

The jQuery function is as follows.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'functions.php?funcion=transaccion&order=' + pedido , 
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        $("#param").val($(xml).find('trxid').text());
        $('#form_pago').submit();
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error en transaccion.");
    }
});
```

The ID is brought back but the form is not submitted.

My guess is that the problem is the form being loaded dinamically so it doesnt exists when the DOM is parsed, but I could not find how to submit it anywhere.

Edit:

Seems that my question was not specific enough or I'm not undestanding the answers because they not solve my problem..

Here a complete version of the code:

This is the function that loads the form.

```
function mostrarFormulario(pedido){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'functions.php?funcion=getFormularioPago&pedido=' + pedido, 
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            $("#fin_pedido").html($(xml).find('formulario').text());
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Se ha producido un error al generar el boton para realizar el pago.");
        }
    }); 
}
```

This is the form being loaded

```
<form method="post" action="https://sps433.decidir.net/sps-ar/Validar" target="_top" id="pago_decidir">  
  <input name="NROCOMERCIO" value="xxxxxxx" type="hidden">
  <input name="NROOPERACION" value="NROOP" type="hidden">
  <input name="MONTO" value="nnnnnnnn" type="hidden">
  <input name="CUOTAS" value="" type="hidden">
  <input name="URLDINAMICA" value="http://URL-RETORNO" type="hidden">
  <input name="EMAILCLIENTE" value="xxxxxx@xxxxxx" type="hidden">
  <input name="MEDIODEPAGO" value="xxxxx" type="hidden">
  <input name="PARAMSITIO" value="" id="paramsitio" type="hidden">
  <input value="Pagar con Decidir" name="submit" alt="Pagar con Decidir" onclick="generarTransaccion('nnn')" border="0" type="button">
</form>
```

And this is the function called in the onClick that should submit the form after retrieving the ID that needs to be sent.

```
function generarTransaccion(pedido) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'functions.php?funcion=transaccion&pedido=' + pedido , 
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
            $("#paramsitio").val($(xml).find('trxid').text());
            $('#pago_decidir').submit();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Se ha producido un error al generar el boton para realizar el pago.");
        }
    }); 
}
```

This function retrieves and replaces correctly the ID but does not submit the form.

Comment: What does `console.log($('#form_pago'))` report if you put it first in the success method?

Comment: You could set a debugger statement in the success callback, and check if in that context, the from_pago was found, also check if the next url is set correctly?

Comment: Maybe show how the form is attached? At least the onsubmit where the first submission is first sending the data to your ajax, and how you change the third party redirection afterwards :)

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific.  The URL is correct because if I change the button for submit it goes correctly to the destination but without the needed ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your Submit with ".on()"
eg

```
$("#formcontainer").on("click", ".dynamicformbutton", function(){
    $('#form_pago').submit();
});
```

Where formcontainer is the id of container you are placing the form into and dynamicformbutton is a class of submit button in the form.

Edit: You will want to put this outside of the ajax call.

Comment: the button has an onClick that executes correctly, its the submit of the form that fails. I edited the question to be more specific and provide additional code

Answer (score 0):

As the form is dynamically loaded, it will not be present in the DOM. So, you need to bind the event to the document listening to click of the submit button.

So, if your form submit button has `Id="btn"`, then this should work -

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
    // do your stuff
    ...
});
```

Comment: the button has an onClick that executes correctly, its the submit of the form that fails.  I edited the question  to be more specific and provide additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this complete code :

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonID', function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'functions.php?funcion=transaccion&order=' + pedido , 
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        $("#param").val($(xml).find('trxid').text());
        $('#form_pago').submit();
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Error en transaccion.");
    }
});
});
```

Put alert("1"); function inside the code, that helps you to check this code working or not. Thanks

Comment: this does nothing for me.  the function is being executed, it's the submit that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding the find function to the form as well
`$('#form_pago').find('form').submit();`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, try to improve your answer maybe giving more details why your answer is correct. Did you try to reproduce your code? Why use `find` if `$f('#form_pago')` is already a form element?